# Requests - determine parameterised url prior to issuing request, for inclusion in Referer header

Tags: python, python-requests, http-referer, referer

I am writing a Python 2.7 script using Requests to automate access to a particular website. The website has a requirement that a Referer header *matching the request URL* is provided, for "security reasons". The URL is built up from a number of items in a `params` dict, passed to requests.post().

Is there a way to determine what the URL that Requests will use is, prior to making the request, so that the Referer header can be set to this correct value? Let's assume that I have a lot of parameters:

```
params = { 'param1' : value1, 'param2' : value2, # ... etc
  }

base_url = "http://example.com"
headers = { 'Referer' : url }   # but what is 'url' to be?
requests.post(base_url, params=params, headers=headers)  # fails as Referer does not match final url
```

I suppose one workaround is to issue the request and see what the URL is, after the fact. However there are two problems with this - 1. it adds significant overhead to the execution time of the script, as there will be a lot of such requests, and 2. it's not actually a useful workaround because the server actually redirects the request to another URL, so reading it afterwards doesn't give the correct Referer value.

I'd like to note that I have this script working with urllib/urllib2, and I am attempting to write it with Requests to see whether it is possible and perhaps simpler. It's not a complicated process the script has to follow, but it may perhaps be slightly beyond the scope of Requests. That's fine, I'd just like to confirm that this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a solution, based on [Prepared Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests). The concept is that `Session.prepare_request()` will do everything to prepare the request except send it, which allows my script to then read the prepared request's url, which now includes the parameters whose order are determined by the dict order. Then it can set the Referer header appropriately and then issue the original request.

```
params = {'param1' : value1, 'param2' : value2, # ... etc
         }
url = "http://example.com"

# Referer must be correct
# To determine correct Referer url, prepare a request without actually sending it
req = requests.Request('POST', url, params=params)
prepped = session.prepare_request(req)
#r = session.send(prepped)   # don't actually send it

# add the Referer header by examining the prepared url
headers = { 'Referer': prepped.url }

# now send normally
r = session.post(url, params=params, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you've found correctly the prepare_request feature in Requests.

However, if you still wanted to use your initial method, I believe you could use your base_url as your Referer:

```
base_url = "http://example.com"
headers = { 'Referer' : base_url }
requests.post(base_url, params=params, headers=headers)
```

I suspect this because your POST has the PARAMS directly attached to the base_url. If, for example, you were on:

```
http://www.example.com/trying-to-send-upload/
```

adding some params to this POST, you would then use:

```
referer = "http://www.example.com/trying-to-send-something/"
headers = { 'Referer' : referer, 'Host' : 'example.com' }
requests.post(referer, params=params, headers=headers)
```

***ADDED***

I would check my URL visually by using a simple statement after you've created the URL string:

```
print(post_url)
```

If this is good, you should print out the details of the reply from the server you're posting to, as it might also give you some hints as to why your query was rejected:

```
s = requests.post(referer, params=params, headers=headers)
print(s.status_code)
print(s.text)
```

Love to hear if this works as well for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this and it came back 403. Looking a bit deeper, it looks like the referer URL for this site *has* to have the params included otherwise it is rejected - is this a quirk of this particular site?

Comment: @meowsqueak, the params hold information critical for the server to understand the POST being made, params = parameters. This could be search details, page details, etc. 403 Forbidden error most likely means either your POST isn't correctly written, or you don't have access to that page. I'd usually suspect the latter, but it's important to make sure you have created a proper post URL.

Comment: This service I am POSTing to requires the referer URL to match the "to" URL, *including parameters*, which I can only get after it has been encoded. That's why I'm using `prepare_request` - to encode the URL and then use it for the Referer. Parameters are added to the base URL from the params argument, so they aren't explicit in the "to" URL or the referer URL initially. I thought it best to let Requests handle the URL encoding, which is why I use the params argument.

Comment: It _sounds_ to me that you understand everything correctly, and are _doing_ it correctly. Actual code would help identify the problem. As I said above, to troubleshoot this you can try a few things. A first step to try and figure out why the server is responding with a 403 Forbidden Error; is because your POST not correctly compiled (this is your params)? or are you not authenticating properly? 

A quick way to see the first is to print(url) after you've compiled it. 

Requests also has documentation on printing the data you sent using the Requests POST command.

Comment: first of all, thank you for your patience with me. From what I can tell, the server is rejecting the POST because the referer header does not contain a URL that also contains the POST parameters. I can't get any more info from the server, it's not under my control. In essence, it looks to me that the server requires both the request URL and the referer URL to be identical for the POST to succeed. It may be a quirk of this server, and it's not public so I can't provide working code unfortunately. Is this an unusual thing for a server to require?